# Is it okay to use synchronous code to load data into the memory at startup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, promise

In my `routes.js` file, I've this:

```
var pages = require('./pages')();
...
app.get('/:page', function(req, res, next) {
    var p = req.params.page;
    if (p in pages) {
        res.render('page', pages[p]);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

`pages.js`:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        ret = [],
        dir = './pages',
        files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        var text = fs.readFileSync(dir + '/' + file, 'utf-8'),
            fileName = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.'));
        ret[fileName] = {content: text};
    });
    return ret;
};
```

This code runs only one, when I run node. This is how I can make it async:

```
require('./pages')(function(pages) {
    app.get('/:page', function(req, res, next) {
        var p = req.params.page;
        if (p in pages) {
            res.render('page', pages[p]);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

`pages.js`:

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        ret = [],
        dir = './pages';
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file, i) {
            fs.readFile(dir + '/' + file, 'utf-8', function(err, text) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var fileName = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.'));
                ret[fileName] = {content: text};
                if ( i === (files.length - 1) ) callback(ret);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Assuming the total pages will not exceed more than 1 MB in size, I can cache the text into memory indefinitely without getting node crashed due to out of memory.

1. Should I be using the async code?

   According to what I've learnt, the async version will make node start listening on localhost faster, but `/:page` URLs will only work when the files have been loaded into memory.
2. Is the async code in the right pattern?
3. What if I need to reuse the `pages` object in another file? Right now it is only accessible in `routes.js`.

Can I rewrite `pages.js` to execute only once like this:

```
var ret = [];
module.exports = function(callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        dir = './pages';
    if (ret.length < 1) {
        fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
            if (err) throw err;
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                fs.readFile(dir + '/' + file, 'utf-8', function(err, text) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var fileName = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    ret[fileName] = {content: text};
                    if ( i === (files.length - 1) ) callback(ret);
                });
            });
        });    
    } else {
        callback(ret);
    }
};
```

4. What if `require('./pages')(function(pages) {})` is called multiple times together? Is there a chance of the `if` condition failing? I can't wrap my mind around this.

Comment: yes, sync loading  (_require_) is how node.js does it, and people seem to still use node.js... there's not a huge payoff in using async to load because the app won't be usable until dependencies are met anyway. once you get going, sync could slow down a bundle of requests, but nothing's happening until everything is loaded, so keep that fast and simple using sync.

Comment: also consider that you're loading from the HDD, not HTTP, so async is not as important as in the browser where sync ajax will freeze the tab and could take a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be using the async code?

If you want, why not. But there's no real need for it, synchronous IO on startup is fine. `require` does it as well.

> Is the async code in the right pattern?

No. It does invoke `callback` once for each directory. Calling `app.get('/:page', …)` multiple times is not what you want.

> What if I need to reuse the pages object in another file? Right now it is only accessible in routes.js.

You could pass it from `routes.js` to the other modules. Or just rewrite `pages.js` to store it statically and execute the async things only once, so that you can require it multiple times.

> What if `require('./pages')(function(pages) {})` is called multiple times together? Is there a chance of the if condition failing?

Yes, it will most certainly fail, because you are populating `ret` only asynchronously.

> I can't wrap my mind around this.

Use promises. The act as asynchronous, unmutable values, just what you need here. They will guarantee that callbacks are only invoked once, that every callback is invoked with the same `ret` value, and provide many more useful things (like managing the parallel file reads for you).

You'll want to export a promise from `pages.js`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I completely missed the fact that the callback in the async code is in a loop. So I can just add an if condition to make sure the callback is called on the last iteration of the loop only, that will fix the async code too, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's horribly complicated, and still has the problem with multiple invocations. Just use sync code or promises.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help. My understanding was `if ( i === (files.length - 1) ) callback(ret);` would do the job (not counting the multiple invocation problem) but `readFile` is async, so the last callback can be executed before the other callbacks are called.

Comment: Yes, you can't use an `i`teration variable from the closure, you will have to use a counter that is increased on every call. But really, you don't want to do that manually, use promises (`Promise.all`) or a helper lib like async.js (`async.parallel`).